# How to cluster keywords or get keywords similarity when I have their vectors

Tags: nlp, word2vec, similarity, cosine-similarity, sentence-similarity

I have got a python-dictionary stored as Vector file with Pickle method (through Bert-as-Service and Google's pretrained model) like:

(key)Phrase : (value)Phrase_Vector_from_Bert = 
woman cloth : 1.3237 -2.6354 1.7458 ....

But I have no idea to get phrases' similarity with the vector files from Bert-as-Service model as I do with Gensim Word2Vec, since the later is equipped with .similarity method.

Would you please give an advice to get phrases/keywords similarity or to cluster them with my python-Pickle-dictionary vector file?

Or maybe is there an better idea to cluster keywords with Bert-as-Service?

The following codes show how I get the vectors for phrases/keywords:

```
import Myutility
# the file Myutility includes the function save_model and load_model

import BertCommand
# the file Bertcommand includes the function to start Bert-as-service 
  client

WORD_PATH = 'E:/Works/testwords.txt'
WORD_FEATURE = 'E:/Works/word.google.vector'

word_vectors = {}

with open(WORD_PATH) as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        line = line.strip('\n')
        if line:                
            word = line
            print(line)
            word_vectors[word]=None

for word in word_vectors:
    try:
        v = bc.encode([word])
        word_vectors[word] = v
    except:
        pass

save_model(word_vectors,WORD_FEATURE)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well, you have yet a vector for each phrase.

Then, you can simply compute cosine similarity between two phrase vectors.

For more details and implementations (manual implementation and sklearn implementation), I suggest this link: https://skipperkongen.dk/2018/09/19/cosine-similarity-in-python/